# MongoDB query to return documents that only have keys amongst a predefined set

Tags: mongodb

The MongoDB query language allows filtering documents based on the existence or absence of a given field with the `$exists` operator.

Is there a way, with the MongoDB syntax, and given a set `K` of allowed fields, to exclude documents that have fields not in `K` from the results, but:

- not knowing in advance which extra fields (outside `K`) can be encountered
- not using JavaScript, that is, the `$where` operator?

**Example:**

```
{
  "Some field" : "foo"
}
{
  "Some field" : "bar",
  "Some other field" : "foobar"
}
```

With the set `K = [ "Some field" ]`, only the first document is to be returned.

Note how this is not to be confused with a projection, which would return both documents but removing the extra field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if MongoDB do support such kind of operations out of box but you can achieve so with help of `mapReduce`.

Assuming your sample data set;

```
// Variable for map
var map = function () {
    var isAcceptable = true;
    Object.keys(this).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key != "_id" && white_list.indexOf(key) == -1) {
            isAcceptable = false;
        }
    });

    if (isAcceptable == true) {
        emit(1, this);
    }
};

// Variable for reduce
var reduce = function (key, values) {
    return values;
};

db.collection.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    {
        scope: {"white_list": ["Some field"]},
        out: {"inline": 1}
    }
);
```

Will return:

```
{ 
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1, 
            "value" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("57cd7503e55de957c62fb9c8"), 
                "Some field" : "foo"
            }
        }
    ], 
    "timeMillis" : 13, 
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 2, 
        "emit" : 1, 
        "reduce" : 0, 
        "output" : 1
    }, 
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Desired result will be in `results.values` of returned document. However, keep in mind limitation of MongoDB `mapReduce` and maximum size of BSON document.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set of known fields `K`, you can construct a query that takes the set as input and gives a query with the **`$exists`** operator along with the corresponding fields projection. Using an example, suppose you have the following documents in a test collection

```
db.test.insert({ "fieldX": "foo", "fieldY": "bar", "fieldZ": 1 })
db.test.insert({ "fieldX": "123", "fieldY": "bar", "fieldZ": 2 })
db.test.insert({ "fieldY": "abc", "fieldZ": 3 })
db.test.insert({ "fieldX": "xyz", "fieldZ": 4 })
db.test.insert({ "fieldZ": 5 })
```

Then you can construct a query `Q` and a projection `P` from an input set `K` as follows:

```
var K = [ "fieldX", "fieldZ" ];  

var or = K.map(function(field) { 
    var obj = {};
    obj[field] = { "$exists": true };
    return obj;
});

var P = K.reduce(function(doc, field) { 
    doc[field] = 1;
    return doc;
}, {} );

var Q = { "$or": or };

db.test.find(Q, P);
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cd78322c241f5870c82b7d"),
    "fieldX" : "foo",
    "fieldZ" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cd78332c241f5870c82b7e"),
    "fieldX" : "123",
    "fieldZ" : 2
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cd78332c241f5870c82b7f"),
    "fieldZ" : 3
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cd78332c241f5870c82b80"),
    "fieldX" : "xyz",
    "fieldZ" : 4
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cd78332c241f5870c82b81"),
    "fieldZ" : 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, I'd expect only documents 4 and 5 to be returned in your example. 1, 2 and 3 don't match the requirement that only `fieldX` and `fieldZ` are allowed to be present, because they contain the not allowed `fieldY`. In other words, only documents `doc` such that `Object.keys(doc)` is a subset of `K` should be returned.